# Anti XSS and Classic ASP

Tags: security, asp-classic, xss

I'm currently trying to secure my classic ASP application from XSS. I came across the AntiXSS from Microsoft on the net and I was wondering if this would work with a classic application?

If not do you have any ideas how I could go about sanitizing the strings?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To sanitize strings I would HTML encode all output, that way you don't have to dink around with special characters or huge regex expressions

```
Server.HTMLEncode(string)
```

The two most important countermeasures to prevent cross-site scripting attacks are to:

- Constrain input.
- Encode output.

via [How To: Prevent Cross-Site Scripting in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998274.aspx) (i know i'ts not classic asp but there are similar principals)

Comment: @Steoates: This, here, is generally a pretty decent solution.

Comment: And if you do have to display rich text (legacy system, sigh), writing a cleanup function to use multiple regular expressions is at least a step in the right direction.

Comment: According to OWASP simply HTMLEncoding is not enough. See: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Why_Can.27t_I_Just_HTML_Entity_Encode_Untrusted_Data.3F

Comment: Yes if you are going to put the user generated code anywhere other than innerHTML then you should use the  Microsoft Anti-Cross Site Scripting Library http://wpl.codeplex.com/

Comment: @rizzle The OP question is "How do I do X?" and your comment is "You should do X"?  Yes, HOW do we do that?

Answer (score 3):

When functions don't exist in classic ASP, write them.

### [Add and strip slashes](https://web.archive.org/web/20150323084634/http://snipplr.com/view/12446/add-and-strip-slashes/)

```
<%
    ' Copyright (c) 2009, reusablecode.blogspot.com; some rights reserved.
    '
    ' This work is licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution License. To view
    ' a copy of this license, visit http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/ or
    ' send a letter to Creative Commons, 559 Nathan Abbott Way, Stanford, California
    ' 94305, USA.
 
    ' Despite the identical naming, these functions are more comprehensive than their PHP equivalents. 
    ' They go above and beyond even mysql_real_escape_string(), by including support for backspace and horizontal tab.
 
    ' List of characters handled:
    ' \000 null
    ' \010 backspace
    ' \011 horizontal tab
    ' \012 new line
    ' \015 carriage return
    ' \032 substitute
    ' \042 double quote
    ' \047 single quote
    ' \134 backslash
    ' \140 grave accent
 
    ' Returns a string with backslashes before characters that need to be quoted in database queries
    function addslashes(unsafeString)
        dim regEx
 
        set regEx = new RegExp
 
        with regEx
            .Global = true
            .IgnoreCase = true
            .Pattern = "([\000\010\011\012\015\032\042\047\134\140])"
        end with
 
        addslashes = regEx.replace(unsafeString, "\$1")
 
        set regEx = nothing
    end function
 
    ' Un-quote string quoted with addslashes()
    function stripslashes(safeString)
        dim regEx
 
        set regEx = new RegExp
 
        with regEx
            .Global = true
            .IgnoreCase = true
            .Pattern = "\\([\000\010\011\012\015\032\042\047\134\140])"
        end with
 
        stripslashes = regEx.replace(safeString, "$1")
 
        set regEx = nothing
    end function
%>
```

### [htmlspecialchars()](https://web.archive.org/web/20170615102915/http://snipplr.com/view/12207/htmlspecialchars)

```
<%
    ' Copyright (c) 2009, reusablecode.blogspot.com; some rights reserved.
    '
    ' This work is licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution License. To view
    ' a copy of this license, visit http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/ or
    ' send a letter to Creative Commons, 559 Nathan Abbott Way, Stanford, California
    ' 94305, USA.
 
    ' Convert special characters to HTML entities.
    function htmlspecialchars(someString)
        ' Critical that ampersand is converted first, since all entities contain them.
        htmlspecialchars = replace(replace(replace(replace(someString, "&", "&amp;"), ">", "&gt;"), "<", "&lt;"), """", "&quot;")
    end function
 
    ' Convert HTML entities to special characters.
    function htmlspecialchars_decode(someString)
        htmlspecialchars_decode = replace(replace(replace(replace(someString, "&amp;", "&"), "&gt;", ">"), "&lt;", "<"), "&quot;", """")
    end function
%>
```

### [strip_tags()](https://web.archive.org/web/20160331172405/https://snipplr.com/view/10608/striptags)

```
<%
    ' Copyright (c) 2008, reusablecode.blogspot.com; some rights reserved.
    '
    ' This work is licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution License. To view
    ' a copy of this license, visit http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/ or
    ' send a letter to Creative Commons, 559 Nathan Abbott Way, Stanford, California
    ' 94305, USA.
 
    ' Strip HTML/ASP/PHP tags from a string.
    function strip_tags(unsafeString)
        dim regEx
 
        set regEx = new RegExp
 
        with regEx
            .Global = true
            .IgnoreCase = true
            .Pattern = "(\<(/?[^\>]+)\>)"
        end with
 
        strip_tags = regEx.Replace(unsafeString, "")
 
        set regEx = nothing
    end function
%>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do have to allow certain HTML tags (as I do in my current project), you can use a regex to allow only those tags and no others, like so:

```
set objRegExp = new RegExp
with objRegExp
    .Pattern = "<^((b)|(i)|(em)|(strong)|(br))>.*</.*>"
    .IgnoreCase = varIgnoreCase
    .Global = True
end with
cleanString = objRegExp.replace(originalString, "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Not easily - you'd need to make a COM-callable wrapper, install on the servers, etc. I simply don't think it is a suitable fit for "classic" ASP.

Answer (score -1):

```
<% 
Response.AddHeader "X-XSS-Protection", "1" 
%>
```

Comment: I know this is a bit old, but X-XSS-Protection header is being deprecated on Chrome, does not work on Firefox, and has already been deprecated from Edge. This is *Not* sufficient protection against XSS. HTML Encoded your output as @missaghi suggests above.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-XSS-Protection