# cross site scripting issues with Fullwidth unicode characters

Tags: xss, unicode-normalization, antixsslibrary

I have developed an application in Asp.net mvc 5.I am facing cross site scripting issues with Full width unicode characters.

Attack value:-%uff1cinput/onclick=alert(1)%uff1e

%uff1c = <
%uff1e = >

I know Antixss library can be used to resolve the issue.But anybody can show a sample code on how to implement Antixss for input filtering and output encoding
Please suggest a solution for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Anti XSS and Classic ASP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/725875/anti-xss-and-classic-asp)

Comment: Oliver my Question is different.How to protect the site from Fullwidth character xss.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and finally found a fix for it. Hopefully this will help anyone else that has the same problem.

Basically, you need to extend the RequestValidator base class that's part of System.Web.Util. Here's my class that will filter out both the unicode values and the actual full width less than and greater than symbols:

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Util;

namespace Common.Extensions
{
    public class RequestValidatorExtension : RequestValidator
    {
        private const string UNICODE_LESS_THAN = "%uff1c";
        private const string UNICODE_GREATER_THAN = "%uff1e";

        public RequestValidatorExtension() { }

        protected override bool IsValidRequestString(
        HttpContext context,
        string value,
        RequestValidationSource requestValidationSource,
        string collectionKey,
        out int validationFailureIndex
        )
        {
            validationFailureIndex = -1;

            if (value.Contains(UNICODE_LESS_THAN))
                value = value.ReplaceWith(UNICODE_LESS_THAN, "<");
            else if (value.Contains("＜"))
                value = value.ReplaceWith("＜", "<");

            if (value.Contains(UNICODE_GREATER_THAN))
                value = value.ReplaceWith(UNICODE_GREATER_THAN, ">");
            else if (value.Contains("＞"))
                value = value.ReplaceWith("＞", ">");

            return base.IsValidRequestString(context, value, requestValidationSource, collectionKey, out validationFailureIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

In my case, when the "malicious" code was added into a text box, it would be passed in as the unicode value. However, when the query string was intercepted by Fiddler and modified, the value would be in the full width symbol. That is why there's a check for both.

You also have to register this new RequestValidationType in the web.config or in your global.asax page. Here's an example of both:

```
// Web.config
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" requestValidationType="namespace.class" />

// Global.asax.cs
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RequestValidator.Current = new RequestValidatorExtension();
}
```

Also, [here's a link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.util.requestvalidator?view=netframework-4.8) to the MS documentation on how to utilize and extend the class.

Hope this helps, cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Just some comments here. The validator will be executed for every single request input, so it's better to make it more efficient. e.g.  value = value.Replace("＜", "<").Replace("＞", ">");

Comment: @Hainan.Z Yes that's a good point. Looking back I probably should've just done it that way. However I did not notice any performance issues with the original code. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Article below, the issue happened because the SQL server will try to convert the Unicode ＜＞ to Ascii version of <> if your database column dost not support nvarchar or nchar. As a result, when the same <> are queried from the database, it becomes XSS injection. 
So essentially there are two ways to fix this. 
1st as @Alec Zorn's answer, you can block them at input. This is a simple and effective approach. 
The 2nd approach is you can change the DB column to use nvarchar or nchar. But this approach will require you to change a lot of columns.

https://www.gosecure.net/blog/2016/03/22/xss-for-asp-net-developers/