# How to fix the XSS attack

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, xss

In our project there is a code potentially causes `XSS` attack. The code accepts a variable `x` as query string and using it in the response like `below`.

```
Dim x : x = Request.QueryString.Item("x") 
Response.Write "document.location.href = 'abc.asp?go=" & x & "&blnJavaOn=y';" & chr(13)
```

Attackers might send some malicious code like `<script>alert()</script>`. How to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Anti XSS and Classic ASP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/725900)

Comment: [Server.HTMLEncode](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/met_htmlencode.asp)